# Android端末のChromeでjavascriptからURLスキームでアプリが起動できません

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-chrome

phpからjavascriptで、Androidアプリを起動するURLスキームを実行しているのですが
アプリが起動してくれません。OPERA等のブラウザは問題なくアプリが起動してくれます。
Chromeの設定なのかjavascriptに問題があるのか原因が掴めず困っています。
OPERA等では起動するのでアプリ側に問題はないと考えています。
何か知っていることがございましたらご教授いただきたいです。

以下はphpのソースです。

```
<?php

echo <<<EOM
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = 'appscheme://';
</script>
EOM;

?>
```

Comment: どこで目にしたかちょっとうろ覚えなのですが、windows.location.href='...'ではなくwindow.location.assign(...)が推奨されているそうです。assign(...)に書き換えるとどうなりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
window.location.assignを確認してみましたが、やはりChromeのみダメでした…

Answer (score 1):

リンク経由で呼び出すには `intent://〜`形式である必要があります。
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/

```
intent:  
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host  
   #Intent;  
      package=\[string\];  
      action=\[string\];  
      category=\[string\];  
      component=\[string\];  
      scheme=\[string\];  
   end;
```